# Google Maps Android API(26876): Authorization failure with Tablet.

Tags: android, dictionary, key

I'm trying to display maps on tablet devices by using google map apiv2.
But I couldn't. 
It works on Smartphones but not on Tablets at all.
So, I'm guessing this is Authorization failure.

Here's Question:
Is there any difference on writing codes for Tablet and Smartphones to display maps by using google map apiv2

Devieces I tested

- Tablet（failed）

  - Android 4.1.2 Tablet
  - Android 4.3 Tablet
- Smartphones（worked）

  - Android 4.0.4 SmartPhone
  - Android 4.1.1 SmartPhone
  - Android 4.1.2 SmartPhone
  - Android 4.2.2 SmartPhone

> Key for Android apps (with certificates)
>
> API key:AI*****c
>   Android apps: Any app allowed
>   Activated on: Oct 6, 2013 12:00 AM
>   Activated by:  android@exmple.co.jp – you

Comment: When ever u run in the different devices you are not able to load the map..

Comment: In Android manifest.xml set the <user-sdk>/past the code         <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: I am facing the same issue did u get any solution for this ???